# A proposition of Urysohn's Lemma in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a problem proving the following theorem, which appears in Evans' PDE text book:

Let $K$ be a compact set in space $R^n$, and $K\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{k} U_{i},k\geq2$, where $U_i$ are open sets. I need to prove that there exists $k$ smooth functions $\{\zeta_i\},i\in\{1,...,k\},0\leq \zeta_i\leq 1$, such that the support of $\zeta_i$, $\operatorname{supp}\zeta_i\subseteq U_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\zeta_i(x)=1, \forall x\in K$

Using the Usysohn's Lemma, I can respectively construct $k$ smooth functions $\{\theta_i\}$ with $0\leq\theta_i\leq1$, whose values are $1$ in compact subsets respectively in $U_i$ and vanish out of $U_i$,then let

$$\zeta_i(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\theta_i}{\sum_j \theta_j}& \text{if } \sum_j \theta_j\neq 0\\
0& \text{if }\sum_j \theta_j= 0
\end{cases}$$

But I can't convince myself that these $\zeta_i$s  are smooth near the boundary of $U_i$. Could anyone give some tips on the construction of $\zeta_i$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: TeX tip: The usual way of writing the support of a function $\varphi$ is "$\operatorname{supp} \varphi$" (`\operatorname{supp} \varphi`). If one is writing an actual TeX document (rather than using MathJax on this or some other site) then one would use `\DeclareMathOperator` in the preamble to define `\supp` as a new math operator.

Comment: So, if $k = 1$ then $\zeta_1$ is the indicator of $U_1$? That's not smooth.

Comment: It seems that if you assure that $\overline{\operatorname{supp}\zeta_i}\subset U_i$ then these $\zeta_i$ will be zero near the boundary of $U_i$.